# How can I find all "*.docx" files in subdirectories, where top-level directories are filtered to numbers only

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem

I'm doing a folder-crawler, finding all docx-files in a subdirectory.
I want only to look in some top-level folders (starting with numbers).
I have a large subdirectory structure with multiple docx-files of different kind and the provided code is very time consuming.

I'm using windows PowerShell without any overlays.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter "*.docx" -Recurse:$true
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. What have you investigated and what is the exact problem?

Comment: build your directory list FIRST then pass use that in your `-Path` value. take a look at `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Parameter path` - note the `-Path <String[]>` means you can give that parameter an _array_ of paths ... [*grin*]

Comment: Excellent. Now I just need to remove items from an Array within a Foreach loop.
Any cool suggestions? -it seems that I cannot use an ArrayList.